# Cake-Like linked-list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I apologize in advance for the total lack of expertise...
but some time ago I was tasked to list out all the factors of a number.
Although I'm certain there are other more efficient ways out there,
the idea that I had in particular was to create a structure that is of such a form:

```
...
struct f{
int a;
struct f *b;
int c;
};

struct f factor = {

{factor_first, factor+1, factor_last},

{factor_second,factor+2, factor_second-to-last},

....(continued)

}
```

So that ultimately the structure would look like:

```
factor = {factor_first, factor_second, factor_third ... ,factor_last}
```

The problem is that:

1) I don't know how many factors there will be, and thus how long the list would be.

2) In the case that I successfully make the list, how can I eliminate the final reference to factor+ some # so that the list would be continuous?

3) I was intending to use the for loop, but realized that I probably can't do something like:

```
if (n%i==0) /* n is the number to be factored, by the way */

factor+i = {i, factor+i+1, n/i}
```

4) So all in all, I'm totally clueless...

Anyhow, I know that there is a better way than this to find the factors of a number,but since I'm a beginner, I was just curious as to how (if possible) I may be able to achieve this.(in this particular way of making a cake-like linked list)

---

After seeing the comment, I decided to try applying it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{

    typedef struct f{
    int a;
    struct f *b;
    int c;
    } FACTOR;

    int n, i, j = 0;

    scanf_s("%d", &n, sizeof(&n)); /*gets n*/

    FACTOR *pTF;
    FACTOR *head = pTF;

    for (i = 1; i*i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            pTF = malloc(sizeof(struct f));
            pTF[j]->a = i;
            pTF[j]->c = n / i;
            pTF[j]->b = malloc(sizeof(struct f));
            pTF[j + 1] = malloc(sizeof(struct f));
            pTF[j]->b = pTF[0 + j + 1];
            j++;
        }

    }
}
```

and somehow it doesn't work... I think it has to do with the
transition between structs and pointers, but I can't seem to grasp it :(

I guess I can't just conveniently call rows by pTF[row number]?
But how else can I do it?

---

So a month later, I came back with a solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct f{
    int s;
    struct f *link;
    int b;
} FACT;

Factprint(FACT *a) //prints this structure in correct sequence.
{
    if(a != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", a->s);
        Factprint(a->link);
        if(a->s!=a->b) printf("%d ", a->b); //skips a square
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num, i;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    FACT *x, *tmp_1, *tmp_2;
    x = malloc(sizeof(FACT));
    tmp_1 = x;
    i = 1;

    for (i = 1; i*i <= num; i++)
    {
        if (num%i == 0) //a factor
        {
            tmp_2 = malloc(sizeof(FACT));
            tmp_2->s = i; //first get the factors
            tmp_2->link = '\0';
            tmp_2->b = num / i;
            tmp_1->link = tmp_2; // then connect to the previous link
            tmp_1 = tmp_2; //now go down the link...
        }
    }

    Factprint(x->link);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a pointer `struct f *pointerToFactor`, and hold the reference to the first factor via `struct f *head = pointerToFator`, to traverse through the linked list when in need.

```
pointerToFactor = malloc(sizeof(struct f));
pointerToFactor->a = factor_first;
pointerToFactor->c = factor_last;
```

and when you get the second factor

```
pointerToFactor->b = malloc(sizeOf(struct f));
struct f *temp = pointerToFactor->b;
temp->a = factor_second;
pointerToFactor->c = factor_second_last;
```

and loop through all the factors this way you have a linked list of all the factors.

**EDIT**

Pointer increment working is quite different. for suppose, I have a Pointer which is pointing to a `structure` whose size is `20`, and base address is 4090. if I increment array, say pointer[1], now the pointer points 5010, the next memory block of `20`. Pointer increment depends on the size of the element is was assigned to.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, would it also be possible to find the factors automatically? I updated the original post with a rudimentary attempt, but it seems quite flawed.

Comment: There is nothing such as automatically, You have to program your logic. However, simply dividing and checking remainder would do the trick.